Confused about python twisted UDP buffer size
I want to use UDP to transmit video streams (pictures). I use twisted, but I encounter a problem. If the sender's packets are larger each time, my server will not receive any messages. I have tested it many times and found that the value should be above 8192, because the server will not work after 9192. I am confused because I have used the built-in UDP of python on the same platform and used a length of 65500.
The following are my two codes, the sender and the receiver. I would be grateful.
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
import numpy as np
import cv2


class VideoServerProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frames = {}

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        count = int.from_bytes(datagram[:4], byteorder='big')
        flag = datagram[4]
        class_id = datagram[5]
        data = datagram[6:]

        if addr not in self.frames:
            self.frames[addr] = {}

        if class_id not in self.frames[addr]:
            self.frames[addr][class_id] = [None] * count

        self.frames[addr][class_id][flag] = data

        if all(part is not None for part in self.frames[addr][class_id]):
            frame_data = b''.join(self.frames[addr][class_id])
            frame = np.frombuffer(frame_data, dtype=np.uint8)
            frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            cv2.imshow('Video Stream', frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            del self.frames[addr][class_id]


def main():
    reactor.listenUDP(9999, VideoServerProtocol())
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
import cv2
import struct


class VideoClientProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE = 8192 - 6  # 65507 is the max UDP payload size minus the header size ########################################################################################################Confused here

    def startProtocol(self):
        self.send_frame()

    def send_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if not ret:
            return

        # Encode frame to bytes
        ret, frame_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame_data = frame_encoded.tobytes()

        count = (len(frame_data) + self.MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE - 1) // self.MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE

        for i in range(count):
            start = i * self.MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE
            end = min((i + 1) * self.MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE, len(frame_data))
            data = frame_data[start:end]
            header = struct.pack('>I', count) + bytes([i]) + bytes([0])  # class_id = 0 for video frame
            self.transport.write(header + data, (self.host, self.port))

        reactor.callLater(0.033, self.send_frame)  # approximately 30 frames per second


def main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 9999
    reactor.listenUDP(0, VideoClientProtocol(host, port))
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I tried to test my sender using the UDP test tool. My sender was normal, but the receiver stopped working when the packet size was too large (datagramReceived function was not called).
Essentially, I want to implement a service layer where multiple UDP senders send video streams to the service layer, and the service layer converts them into MJPEG streams that can be accessed by multiple HTTP clients. I have already implemented a simple one using TCP, but the latency was high, so I wanted to try UDP.

Are you sending UDP over the virtual loopback interface on a single machine or via a physical network? In the latter case you are probably facing problems with PMTU, fragmentation and (just a guess) ICMP blocked by a firewall.
